# Making a python based website with a email collect feature but crashes when input email

Tags: python, html, templates, flask

I making a website for an eagle project and part of it people can submit emails so i can contact them later.
The html looks like this:

```
{%extends "layout.html"%}
{%block content%}
<div class= "contact">
    <h1>How can you help?</h1>
    <br>
    <p>
        The biggest way to help is to <strong>DONATE</strong> to the Eagle project.
        Another way that you can help is to volunteer on a work day. This counts
        for volunteer hours.
    </p>
    <br>
    <h2>Donations</h2>
    <p>you can donate in the following ways</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">CashApp</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Venmo</a></li>
        <li>Or a check made out to <strong>lorem</strong></li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Volunteer</h2>
    <p>If you would like to volunteer enter your email below and I will contact you</p>
    <form action="contact" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder = "enter email here">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>My email:lorem</li>
        <li>My number: lorem</li>
    </ul>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

And the python back end looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect,request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/contact/", methods = ["POST"])
def signup():
    file=open("email_list", "a")
    email = request.form["email"]
    file.write(email+"\n")
    file.close()

    return redirect("/")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/about/")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

@app.route("/contact/")
def contact():
    return render_template("contact.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When ever i enter an email I get: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again
Can anyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your form:

You have:

```
<form action="contact" method="post">
```

And should be

```
<form action="{{url_for('signup')}}" method="POST">
```

Notice that inside `{{url_for('signup')}}` I wrote `'signup'` because in your python code `def signup():`has control over your form.